# automate VSTS load test with Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-devops, load-testing

I have built a release pipeline in VSTS to deploy a static website to an Azure Web App. I'm now trying to set up an automated load test against the Azure Web App using VSTS.

I've created and successfully ran a URL based test in VSTS, I've then exported the test to Zip file and grabbed the loadtest and cloudsettings file. Within the WebApp I have created a LoadTest directory in `D:\home` and added the load test and cloud settings files.

Within VSTS I have added a Cloud Load test task to the pipeline. To add the Cloud Load Test task I edited the pipeline, selected Tasks from the menu, and added a Cloud Load Test task. I've specified the load test file and cloud settings and in 'Load test files folder', I have entered `D:\home\LoadTest`. An Image of the configuration can be found [here](https://djpimages.blob.core.windows.net/images/VSTSCapture.JPG)

The D:\home folder sits in the Azure WebApp. I accessed it via the advanced console, created a LoadTest directory in there and added the load test files and settings.

The problem is that the **load test always fails when the I initiate a deployment**. **It claims the `D:\home\LoadTest` folder does not exist**.

The error in the log file was:

[error]Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException: The path for the load test files D:\home\LoadTest\ does not exist. Please provide a valid path.
2018-08-29T13:31:59.8138811Z ##[error]PowerShell script completed with 1 errors.
2018-08-29T13:31:59.8147407Z ##[section]Finishing: Cloud Load Test CDDemoApp.loadtest

I've tried a few different variations but can't seem to get this to work.

Does anyone know the location within the Web App the load test and cloud settings should be dropped in order for VSTS to successfully pick them up?

Comment: How do you configure the Cloud Load Test task in release pipeline? And Where does th "D:\home" folder? On Azure Web App side, VSTS repository side or agent machine?

Comment: How did you configure your release artifacts?

Comment: I've added the requested information to the post